# How to query an object of objects in mysql json column

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysql-json

I have an `order_summary` JSON column in my `orders` table with the following structure

```
{
  "total": 16.895,
  "products": { // products is an object of objects instead of array of objects
    "98": {
      "price": "2.400",
      "quantity": 2,
      "sub_total": 4.8,
      "product_id": 100,
      "variant_id": 98
    },
    "395": {
      "price": "3.900",
      "quantity": 1,
      "sub_total": 3.9,
      "product_id": 401,
      "variant_id": 395
    },
    "732": {
      "price": "7.695",
      "quantity": 1,
      "sub_total": 7.695,
      "product_id": 754,
      "variant_id": 732
    }
  }
}
```

**What I am trying to do,**

I have to calculate the total number of items sold for a given `variant_id`, So I want to fetch the sum the `quantity` field inside the `products` object.

**The problem**

Sadly the products field is not an array of objects instead its an object of objects. With the keys being `variant_id` itself. So my following query is not working

`SELECT sum(order_summary->"$.products.quantity") FROM orders where order_summary->"$.products.variant_id" = 98` (which returns an empty result set)

I think this is because of the presence of the keys in the products array. So how can I tackle this?

I am using Mysql 8, kindly let me know if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error and with the help of a friend, I found the following solution,

```
SELECT SUM(order_summary -> '$.products."98".quantity') as sum
FROM orders
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(order_summary, 'all', '$.products."98"')
```